# php regex - remove \r\n\r\n at the very beginning AND at the very end in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, line-breaks, carriage-return

**If exists, I need to remove `\r\n\r\n` at the very beginning and/or at the very end of string.**

My issue is I couldn't achieve my aim with codes below.

```
//if exists, remove \r\n\r\n at the very beginning
$str = preg_replace('/^(\r\n\r\n)/', '', $str);

//if exists, remove \r\n\r\n at the very end
$str = preg_replace('/$(\r\n\r\n)/', '', $str);
```

maybe my html output's source view can give some clues to you. I don't know the reason but `<br />` tags are not side-by-side. They position as one-under-the-other.

```
<br />
<br />
some text
...
...
some text<br />
<br />
```

Also below, I share my whole string manipulation code. My problematic 2 rows of code is a part of the code below. (The other parts except 2 rows of code above works well)

```
function convert_str ($str)
{
    // remove excess whitespace
    // looks for a one or more spaces and replaces them all with a single space.
    $str = preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $str);
    // check for instances of more than two line breaks in a row
    // and then change them to a total of two line breaks
    $str = preg_replace('/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/s', "\r\n\r\n", $str);
    //if exists, remove \r\n\r\n at the very beginning
    $str = preg_replace('/^(\r\n\r\n)/', '', $str);

    //if exists, remove \r\n\r\n at the very end
    $str = preg_replace('/$(\r\n\r\n)/', '', $str);

    //if exists, remove 1 space character just before any  \r\n
    $str = str_replace(" \r\n", "\r\n", $str);
    //if exists, remove 1 space character just after any \r\n
    $str = str_replace("\r\n ", "\r\n", $str);  
    // if exists; remove 1 space character just before punctuations below:
    // $punc = array('.',',',';',':','...','?','!','-','—','/','\\','“','”','‘','’','"','\'','(',')','[',']','’','{','}','*','&','#','^','<','>','|');
    $punc = array(' .',' ,',' ;',' :',' ...',' ?',' !',' -',' —',' /',' \\',' “',' ”',' ‘',' ’',' "',' \'',' (',' )',' [',' ]',' ’',' {',' }',' *',' &',' #',' ^',' <',' >',' |');
    $replace = array('.',',',';',':','...','?','!','-','—','/','\\','“','”','‘','’','"','\'','(',')','[',']','’','{','}','*','&','#','^','<','>','|');
    $str = str_replace($punc,$replace,$str);
    return $str;
}
```

Can you please correct me?

Thanks

BR

Comment: You know about [**trim**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) right?

Comment: @elclanrs my faulty insistence for using preg_replace made me blind I think until trim mentioning answers. I shamed. thanks so much. your comment is a good lesson for me.

Comment: also using regex for a stringreplace that easy is really bad!

Comment: @AndreChenier remember. if you can write down what you want to replace without no further conditions then you don't need regex. if it even is just whitespace then trim is enough. otherwise use str_replace.

Comment: @AndreChenier: it happens all the time. PHP standard library is huge, it's easy to miss functionality that is there. But once you use it you'll never forget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) string function to handle this.

> trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

**Example:**

```php
$str = trim($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
//if exists, remove \r\n\r\n at the very end
$str = preg_replace('/$(\r\n\r\n)/', '', $str);
```

by

```
//if exists, remove \r\n\r\n at the very end
$str = preg_replace('/(\r\n\r\n)$/', '', $str);
```

You can also try to use the [Trim function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.trim.php) (e.g. **string trim ( string $str [, string $charlist = " \t\n\r\0\x0B" ] )** )